# How to achieve relavent search in mongodb with partial text matching

Tags: mongodb, search, aggregate, regexp-like

Suppose I have a list of products in my mongodb collection named products, with the following test data as follows

> Samsung Mobile Phone

> Samsung Fridge

> Samsung Washing Machiene

I Could active relavant search by using the following mongo aggregate query

```
db.products.aggregate(
    [{
        "$match": {
            "$and": [{
                "status": "active"
            }, {
                "delete": false
            },  { 
                "$text": { $search: "Samsung Mobile" } 
            }]
        }
    },
    { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }
    ]
);
```

The problem is that I could not get result with partial keyword for example "Samsun" . This will give empty result for me , full aggregate query with empty result is given below

```
db.products.aggregate(
    [{
        "$match": {
            "$and": [{
                "status": "active"
            }, {
                "delete": false
            },  { 
                "$text": { $search: "Samsun" } 
            }]
        }
    },
    { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }
    ]
);
```

Comment: MongoDB is not primarily a text search database. Use Elasticsearch or something else in addition to the MongoDB.

Comment: @Clashsoft Does it work along with existing mongodb database, My system already have a large set of products. Could you please provide more explanation for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Using `$text` to search on things like a product name is overkill given that product names will only be a few words at most. In mongodb `$text` is best for things like a product description or specifications so that your users can search for keywords that might appear in a short paragraph about the product or a review etc. For things like product name I would recommenced a simple [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#-regex) to look for a partial match despite the fact you won't get a `textScore` value like so:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "status": "active",
      "delete": false,
      "name": {
        $regex: "Samsun",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Or if you don't intend on doing further `aggregate` stages then a simple `find` will do the job like so:

```js
db.products.find({
  "status": "active",
  "delete": false,
  "name": {
    $regex: "Samsun",
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

If you are using Atlas then you can do a partial match with `wildcard` or `autocomplete`.
The excellent [How to Run Partial Match Atlas Search Queries](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/partial-match/#how-to-run-partial-match-fts-queries) resource has a few Node code samples that explain it pretty well but will require a little bit of preconfiguration.

Comment: The problem is with local mongodb is that the relavent search will work only if exact worrd comes.  So from your comment are you telling that If I use atlas, both relavent serch will work along with partial keyword?

Comment: `$text` search uses an index to look for exact *words* or *phrases* or exclude a word from the search. There is no partial match. But if you are using Atlas then you can use [wildcard](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/wildcard/#std-label-wildcard-ref) as an additional feature which will enable partial match as per the link in the answer. @Ajith